# Calling a Django command in a unittest code

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-commands

I am trying to use `call_command` to download data from a URL and was wondering on how to call it from the code.

I have declared the option lists as follows in my code:

```
option_list = BaseCommand.option_list + (
        make_option('--url', default=None, dest='url', help=_(u'Specifies the full url of the json data to download.')),
        make_option('--username', default=None, dest='username', help=_(u'Login of the person doing the download.')),
        make_option('--password', default=None, dest='password', help=_(u'Password of the person doing the download.')),
        make_option('--file', default=None, dest='file', help=_(u'File name of the json data to download in gzip-compressed-data format')),
    )
```

I use it as follows from the command line:

```
./manage.py download --url=http://some-link.com/download/ --username=admin --password=admin
```

So far I have the following:

```
call_command('download')
```

How do I pass in the rest of the parameters/args?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass them as keyword arguments:

```
call_command('download', 
             url="http://some-link.com/download/", 
             username="admin",
             password="admin")
```

The keyword arguments should reflect the `dest` values of your custom management command arguments.

---

Example for `flush` command:

`--initial-data` command-line argument in `call_command()` can be set by passing [`load_initial_data` keyword argument](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/management/commands/flush.py#L26):

```
call_command('flush', load_initial_data=False)
```

This is because it is `--initial-data`'s argument destination:

```
parser.add_argument('--no-initial-data', action='store_false',
    dest='load_initial_data', default=True,
    help='Tells Django not to load any initial data after database synchronization.')
```